# Spotify API is missing the "publisher" field in its response

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, spotify

I'm doing a project for uni right now and I need to make an API Call to the Spotify API for an android app. Everything works as expected and hasn't given me much trouble but for some reason the "publisher" field in Spotify's response is empty.

I've tried setting it manually to be not-nullable but that just crashes the app because it's not being transmitted.

The Spotify API documentation also states, that the field should be present within the response.
(https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-a-show)

This is my code (Kotlin with Gradle):

```
@Composable
fun DisplayPodcastInfo(podcastLink: String, spotifyAccessToken: String) {
    var podcastInfo by remember { mutableStateOf<PodcastInfo?>(null) }

    //because no episode can be pulled with a request, need to pull all and search for the requested one
    val showId: String
    val episodeId: String

    if (podcastLink.contains("/show/")) {
        showId = podcastLink.substringAfter("/show/").substringBefore("?", "")
        episodeId = ""
    } else if (podcastLink.contains("/episode/")) {
        episodeId = podcastLink.substringAfter("/episode/").substringBefore("?", "")
        showId = ""
    } else {
        Log.e("PodcastInfo", "Invalid podcast link: $podcastLink")
        return
    }

    if (episodeId.isNotEmpty()) {
        LaunchedEffect(episodeId) {
            val httpClient = HttpClient {
                install(JsonFeature) {
                    serializer = KotlinxSerializer(json = kotlinx.serialization.json.Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true })
                }
            }

            //building the request
            val episode: PodcastInfo = httpClient.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/episodes/$episodeId") {
                headers {
                    append("Authorization", "Bearer $spotifyAccessToken")
                }
                parameter("market", "DE")
            }

            podcastInfo = episode
            Log.w("Spotify API Res", "Response: \n $episode")
        }

    } else if (showId.isNotEmpty()) {
        Log.e("PodcastInfo", "invalid link, $podcastLink the podcast link might be the $podcastInfo")
    } else {
       Log.e("PodcastInfo", "Invalid podcast link: $podcastLink")
   }...
```

And this is the data-structure I'm using to parse the response:

```
@Serializable
data class PodcastInfo(
    val audio_preview_url: String? = null,
    val description: String? = null,
    val duration_ms: Float? = null,
    val explicit: Boolean? = null,
    val name: String,
    val publisher: String? = null,
    val images: List<SpotifyImage>,
    val id: String,
    val uri: String? = null
)
```

(note that I'm using the "ignoreUnknownKeys = true" installable to avoid having to extend my PodcastInfo class)

I have no idea how that would happen.

I tried several different podcasts, "publisher: String" (crashes the app), and still it won't get a value..

Comment: I've tested the endpoint with to show IDs, and it displayed the publisher without a problem.